# Kotlin config for few flavors

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got the problem with configuration of my project for few flavors. I have 2 env-s, for staging and production one. Its config set into `flavor-stage/Env.java` and `flavor-prod/Env.java` and it works as expected when you work with java code and visible from Kotlin classes too, but it crashes during compiling with

```
Error:(19, 23) Unresolved reference: Env
```

It seems Kotlin can resolve classes from another flavor' folder. Please help to config it. My gradle.build is:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.6"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `productFlavors` definition as well as your project structure and the code where the error occurs. Also the gradle tasks for which you get the error can be helpful.

Comment: there is simple standard structure ( flavors with no extra config )

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the latest Kotlin version which is `1.1.0`. Tested this case and it worked for me. Here is a sample project, hope it helps. https://github.com/4u7/android-flavor-demo

And check your directory structure. For my Env files I used:

`/src/prod/java/com/myapp/flavor/EnvKotlin.kt`
`/src/stage/java/com/myapp/flavor/EnvKotlin.kt`